# I have written some code for my users to log in to my app, but email and password column doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

With the help of Chris Coding on youtube, I have tried to open a authViewController where my users should be able to sign up. So when I try it out I can reach the authViewController but the email and password column doesn't appear in the screen. So does anyone have an idea where the problem may occur?

```
@IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: Any) {  
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

    guard authUI != nil else {
        return
    }
    authUI?.delegate = self

    let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()

    present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


extension ViewController:  FUIAuthDelegate{

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?,error: Error?){

        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one theory that its because I imported FirebaseUI, instead of FirebaseUI \ Auth, but that's because the second one didn't work and I reed something about that with the new update FirebaseUI work

Comment: The first line looks suspicious to me if you are trying to unwrap "authUI" should be guard let authUI != nil else { return } then the "?" should be removed.

Comment: Or even better `guard let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() else { return }`

Comment: I don't see where you've fully configured the controller. Please go back to the Firebase Authentication [Pre Built Sign In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#sign_in) and follow the steps - you're missing a bit of code.

Comment: Have done that but aren't able to find the missing piece.. @Jay

Comment: The code in the Firebase Guide is totally missing from the code in your question. Where is this `self.authUI.providers = providers` or `if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen`?

Comment: I get an error message when I do so.. @DavidLintin

Comment: Cant find it in the pre built UI section.. @Jay

Comment: Not sure what you are saying as if you click the link in my comment above and look at the code in the guide, it is different from your code.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood but the missing code were  "authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth()]" @Jay